# Converter HTML para XML

Tags: html, c#, xml, mongodb-csharp

Estou com dificuldades para converter um arquivo HTML em XML.
O arquivo possui uma tabela que quero converter em dados.
Nesse arquivo HTML existe uma anotação comentada que indica onde começa o relatório.
Já busquei informações com HtmlAgilityPack e não consegui resolver.

Tem uma atribuição de classe para as linhas que preciso "even" , mas não achei nada que possa usar a classe da tag para buscar os dados.
Tentei salvar em arquivo texto pra tentar ler linha por linha, mas o StremReader não aceita as tags, ou seja lá o que for, mas está negando.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz, indicar alguma documentação pra isso, agradeço demais.

Segue HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
<base href="https://sitederelatorio.com"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bGeneratedReport"><div class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd">
<!-- /opp/rptopptprod.jsp -->
<div class="pbHeader"></div><div class="pbBody"><div class="pbSubblock"><div class="pbSubheader"><a href="/00dsN" style="font-family: sans-serif"><strong>PedidosHeader</strong></a></div><div class="pbSubbody"><div class="reportHeader"><p>Executar como: TI<br/>Executar em: 29/12/2022 22:06</p><input type="hidden"  id="nav" name="nav" value="" /><div class="filterHeader"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td colspan="2"><input type="hidden"  id="deletefilter" name="deletefilter" value="" /><input type="hidden"  id="deleteObjfilter" name="deleteObjfilter" value="" /><span  class="filteredBy">Filtrado por:</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="5">Campo de data: Data da última mudança de status igual a Últimos 7 dias (23/12/2022 para 29/12/2022)</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="5">Mostrar: Todos os pedidos</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="5">Status do pedido: Qualquer</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="5">Probabilidade: Tudo</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap colspan="5"><span  class="filterField">Distribuidor</span>&nbsp;<span  class="filterOp">contém</span>&nbsp;<span  class="filterValue">lubexx</span>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap colspan="5">E <span  class="filterField">Pedido filho</span>&nbsp;<span  class="filterOp">igual a</span>&nbsp;<span  class="filterValue">Verdadeiro</span>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td nowrap colspan="5">E <span  class="filterField">Código filial</span>&nbsp;<span  class="filterOp">diferente de</span>&nbsp;<span  class="filterValue">02</span>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div></div><br/><div class="reportOutput">


<!-- Start report output -->


<div id="fchArea">
<table class="reportTable tabularReportTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr id='headerRow_0' bgcolor='#aaaaff' class='headerRow'>
<TH align="left" scope="col">Número do pedido</TH><TH align="left" scope="col">ID customizado</TH><TH align="right" scope="col">Data de criação</TH><TH align="right" scope="col">Data da última mudança de status</TH><TH align="left" scope="col">Status</TH><TH align="left" scope="col">Código do vendedor</TH><TH align="left" scope="col">Vendedor</TH><TH align="left" scope="col">Código condição de pagamento</TH><TH align="right" scope="col">Data da última modificação</TH><TH align="left" scope="col">Call Center</TH></tr>
<tr class="even" valign="top"><td >20220623-10519433</td><td >I101000897B1</td><td align="right">23/06/2022</td><td align="right">23/12/2022</td><td >Faturado</td><td >00042</td><td ><a href="/a18tO">RAFAEL</a></td><td >76</td><td align="right">23/12/2022</td><td >VANESSA</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#aaaacc' class='grandTotal grandTotalTop'><td colspan="10"><strong>Totais gerais (365 registros)</strong></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#aaaacc' class='grandTotal' valign="top"><td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
<td class="nowrapCell" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div></div></div></div></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Acho que encontrei a resposta.
O caminho é o [HTML-Agility-Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net) mesmo. Porém pra encontrar o índice da linha que estou lendo, a partir do comentário no HTML, tive que salvar tudo em um arquivo e gerar um array com os valores do arquivo texto gerado.

Primeiro peguei tudo que tinha já salvo em html e gerei um arquivo, para depois gerar um array a partir do arquivo texto.
A explicação está nos comentários do código.
Tentei reduzir ao máximo o aninhamento desse código. Vocês precisavam ver o tanto de if que tinha nisso.
Se alguém puder deixar isso mais elegante, agradeço.

```
    public string GetDataFromTags(string html){
   
    //índices para início e fim da busca de dados na string do html
    int indiceIni=0, indiceFim=0;
    
    //array para receber os dados sem as tags
    string[] valuesExtract = new string[10];
    
    //objeto HtmlAgilityPack para tratar as tags
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    
    
    //grava html em arquivo texto para mandar para um array indexado.
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("\\Test.txt");
    sw.WriteLine(html);
    sw.Close();
    
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("\\Test.txt");
    
    
    //Define o início e o fim do relatório
    for (int indice = 0; indice < lines.Length; indice++)
    {
        //busca a linha que inicia o relatório
        if (lines[indice].Contains("<|-- Start report output -->"))
        {
            //+2 pra pular o cabeçalho da tabela
            indiceIni = indice + 2; 
        }
        if(lines[indice].Contains("Totais gerais"))
        {
            //linha onde é o final do relatório
            indiceFim = indice;
        }
    }
    
    //Aqui eu inicio a tratativa de dados conforme linhas encontradas acima
    for(int indice = indiceIni; indice < indiceFim; indice++)
    {
        //Recebo a primeira linha
        string dados = lines[indice];
        
        //HtmlAgilityPack
        doc.LoadHtml(dados);
        
        //aqui eu pego apenas todas as tags TD.. e apenas elas
        var htmlNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr//td");
        int indexExtract = 0;
        foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
        {
            
            //aqui é o pulo do gato
            //extraio apenas os dados dentro das tags TD.
            //salvo em um array para ser iterado depois 
            //salvando em um objeto para depois levar para o banco de dados.
            valuesExtract[indexExtract] = node.InnerText;
            indexExtract++;
        }
            
    }
}
```

O Array **valuesExtract** contem um campo em cada linha de registro. O que facilita pra jogar na classe certa e mandar pro banco de dados.